# save dynamically created form fields between page requests

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have a form in which the user can dynamically add/remove name/value pairs of fields eg:

```
inventory list:
[description text input field] [quantity text input field] [remove item button]
[add item button]
```

so basically the user can add more inventory items:

```
inventory list:    
[description text input field] [quantity text input field] [remove item button]
[description text input field] [quantity text input field] [remove item button]
[description text input field] [quantity text input field] [remove item button]
[add item button]
```

ok so what is the easiest way to save the form state if server side field validation fails, or if the user wants to later edit the custom-created form? (i don't think it is of any relevance but I am using JQuery and CakePHP)

Comment: the data will be saved in a database table inventory_lists with name/value columns

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) to make the request, which will prevent the client from having to re-render the entire page.

Comment: hmmm i was considering that but i want server side form validation

Comment: You can still use Cake's server side validation: http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/cakephp_form_validation_with_ajax_using_jquery.php

Comment: Let me rephrase that for you:  you *need* server-side validation.  And that's no problem.